# SQL: first row of group by after join and order

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assuming we got two below tables:

**TravelTimes**

```
OriginId     DestinationId   TotalJourneyTime 
    1               1              10
    1               2              20
    2               2              30
    2               3              40
    1               3              50
```

**Destinations**

```
DestinationId           Name
      1               Destination 1
      2               Destination 2
      3               Destination 3
```

How do I find the quickest journey between each origin and destination?
I want to join TravelTimes with Destinations by DestinationId and then group them by OriginId and sort each group by TotalJourneyTime and select the first row of each group.
I did try joining and grouping, but it seems group by is not the solution for my case as I don't have any aggregation column in the output.

**Expected output**

```
OriginId    DestinationId   DestinationName     TotalJourneyTime
   1             1              Destination 1       10
   2             3              Destination 3       40
```

Comment: please post your expected output and your attempt

Comment: @vkp I have posted the expected output. I will post what I tried, however that is simple and incomplete.

Comment: Where is 2-2 in the output?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri 2-2 shouldn't be in the output because 1-2 is quicker that 2-2.

Comment: Im a little confused by that. 2-2 is a different journey to 1-2

Comment: Why can't you use travel time as the aggregation column with a `MIN` applied?

Comment: @Tanner That's right, I could have use MIN. My mistake..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [`RANK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms176102.aspx) to rank each journey partitioned by the origin and destination and ordered by the travel time

```
WITH RankedTravelTimes
AS
(
   select originid, 
       destinationId, 
       totaljourneytime, 
       rank() over (partition by originid,destinationid order by totaljourneytime ) as r
   from traveltimes
)
SELECT rtt.*, d.name
FROM RankedTravelTimes rtt
INNER JOIN Destinations d
   ON rtt.destinationId = d.id
WHERE rtt.r=1
```

The above will include both the journey from 1-2 and 2-2 as separate. If you're only interested in the *destination* you can remove `originId` out of the partition.

Comment: i think as per the question, the `partition by` should only be on `destinationid`

Comment: @Jamiec Thanks. I have converted your solution in an SQL Fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fc0e0/3
I am wondering why it returns five rows while I expect this to return only three rows which are one closest destination per 1 origin.

Comment: @shaahin the sqlfiddle, and your original question have different data. the fiddle has 5 unique rows (in terms of origin/destination) so they are *all* ranked `1`

Comment: @Jamiec I have update the fiddle => http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3a436/1
I am not looking for the best rank per origin/destination. I am looking for best origin per best destination. Basically, the output should only return 3 rows as I showed at the end of my question.

Comment: And thats exactly what I explained at the end of my answer: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3a9bf/3

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I see the problem here with just joining and grouping the data with a `MIN` on the journey time:

```
CREATE TABLE #Traveltimes
    (
      [OriginId] INT ,
      [DestinationId] INT ,
      [TotalJourneyTime] INT
    );

INSERT  INTO #Traveltimes
        ( [OriginId], [DestinationId], [TotalJourneyTime] )
VALUES  ( 1, 1, 10 ),
        ( 1, 2, 20 ),
        ( 2, 2, 30 ),
        ( 2, 3, 40 ),
        ( 2, 3, 50 );


CREATE TABLE #Destinations
    (
      [DestinationId] INT ,
      [Name] VARCHAR(13)
    );

INSERT  INTO #Destinations
        ( [DestinationId], [Name] )
VALUES  ( 1, 'Destination 1' ),
        ( 2, 'Destination 2' ),
        ( 3, 'Destination 3' );

SELECT  d.DestinationId ,
        d.Name ,
        tt.OriginId ,
        MIN(tt.TotalJourneyTime) MinTime
FROM    #Destinations d
        INNER JOIN #Traveltimes tt ON tt.DestinationId = d.DestinationId
GROUP BY tt.OriginId ,
        d.DestinationId ,
        d.Name

DROP TABLE #Destinations
DROP TABLE #Traveltimes
```

Gives you:

```
DestinationId   Name                OriginId    MinTime
1               Destination 1       1           10
2               Destination 2       1           20
2               Destination 2       2           30
3               Destination 3       2           40
```

Note: why do you travel from destination 1 to itself?

Comment: Thanks. I have converted your solution to an SQL Fiddle => http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fc0e0/1
About traveling from a destination to itself, that's not right. Because origins and destinations are supplying through different tables.
Is there any way to change to query to only return the quickest origin per destination? In your answer, it has returned two records for destination 2.

Comment: @shaahin they have different origins though? do you not want that as they are unique trips?

Comment: Not really. All is important is finding the quickest trip per destination which will be as expected output that I showed in my question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the following:

```
;with cte as(select *, row_number() over(partition by DestinationId order by TotalJourneyTime) rn 
             from TravelTimes)
select * from cte c
join Destinations d on c.DestinationId = d.DestinationId 
where c.rn = 1
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for . Many Thanks.