# How to get 1st occurrence of all rows in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

The question is pretty simple--I need to get the 1st occurrence of a specific value in order to avoid duplicates. The table in question logs every user interaction in an application, so there are millions of rows that possibly, probably, duplicate information. I'll put a few test records just to show what I mean by duplicate information, and then my query to show how I am pulling in this information.

```
ID    CreateDate           KeyValue      OldValue    NewValue
01    1/2/2016 12:46:53    000001-1-0    NULL        O
02    1/2/2016 12:47:58    000001-1-0    NULL        O
03    1/2/2016 12:46:53    000001-2-0    NULL        O

SELECT DISTINCT CreateDate, KeyValue
FROM capp.dbo.Log
WHERE Message = 'stat'
    AND OldValue IS NULL
    AND NewValue = 'O'
    AND CreateDate >= '01/01/2016'
```

The results that I would like the query to pull in should be just row 1 and 3, and exclude row 2 because it has a duplicate KeyValue. However, I have tried DISTINCT ON (KeyValue), MIN(KeyValue), and GROUP BY statements and yet the 2nd record remains. Ideally, the 2nd record, as I have written it, would never have been inserted into the table because the OldValue would be "O" and not "NULL", but I have no control over this 3rd party application.

I think the answer is simple, but I am currently donkey brained.

Comment: some languages do:  `select top(1) * from table` whereas others say `select * from table limit 1`

Comment: The `CreateDate` column is not distinct, that is why the `distinct` is not working. Try `SELECT DISTINCT CAST(CreateDate AS DATE) AS CreateDate, KeyValue
FROM capp.dbo.Log
WHERE Message = 'stat'
    AND OldValue IS NULL
    AND NewValue = 'O'
    AND CreateDate >= '01/01/2016'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL: first row of group by after join and order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34067692/sql-first-row-of-group-by-after-join-and-order)

Comment: I know the CreateDate is not distinct, that's why I was trying to use distinct on the KeyValue field only. I also have to keep the date fields with the timestamp b/c later on I use a DATEDIFF function on the days and hours between 2 dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT ID, CreateDate, KeyValue
FROM (
  SELECT ID, CreateDate, KeyValue,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY KeyValue 
                            ORDER BY CreateDate) AS rn
  FROM capp.dbo.Log
  WHERE Message = 'stat'
        AND OldValue IS NULL
        AND NewValue = 'O'
        AND CreateDate >= '01/01/2016') AS t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The underlying problem is that SQL does not promise that the data are in any particular order, nor that a select statement will return the data in a particular order.
The answer that adds ROW_NUMBER will give you a unique KeyValue and CreateDate for each record, but that may not be the record that you expected.  If there is a record you want, try to add another field that can be used to select on.